# php codeigniter uri

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

i am trying to redirect to a controller using an external js file so that my url address bar will look like  [this is not a link] (http:/project/index.php/TravellerController/create/1)
my code in the  javascript looks like this:

```
u55.style.cursor = 'pointer';
$axure.eventManager.click('u55', function(e) {

if (true) {
self.location.href=$axure.globalVariableProvider.getLinkUrl('TravellerController');

}
});
```

the u55 is the id of the link in my "home" views  file
my TravellerController looks like this:

```
<?php
class TravellerController extends CI_Controller {
public function index()                                        
{
$data=$this->get_data();
}
function get_data(){
*some code...*
redirect('TravellerController/create/'.$data);
{
function create(){
*some code...*
}
}
?>
```

so if i click on that link my url address field then looks like this:

[this is not a link] (http:/project/index.php/home/create/TravellerController)

BUT I WANT IT TO LOOK LIKE THIS:

[this is not a link] (http:/project/index.php/TravellerController/create/1)

Comment: in other words its only getting the same one row of data even when different users log in

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you are not getting the logged in user from the database based on the userid. When the user logs in you store the values in a session, which is good, but you need to find the logged in user in your database.

Add a new function to your model:

```
function getUser($userid) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('profile');
    $this->db->where('id', $userid);
    $query = $this->db->get()->result();
    return $query;
}
```

And in your controller change:

```
$data['info'] = $this->profileModel->get_all_info();
```

to

```
$data['info'] = $this->profileModel->getUser($session_data['id']);
```

I'm not totally sure with your 2 tables, so above code is basically an example. If your username is unique in the table, you can also use that to get the correct user from your database.

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: can you do a var_dump in your controller from info and see if it has a user? var_dump($data['info']);

Comment: ok i did exactly that but i got this error on my browser "
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/profile.php

Line Number: 51"
and this line 51 contains this code"<?php foreach ($info as $u_key){ ?>" i had put this code in my view so that it will populate i.e read from the db and display user profile information for example his title and country. the $info array is passed data from "function update_info($data,$id)" as in my model which is and in the controller i use $data['info'] = $this->profileModel->get_all_info();

Comment: I edited the model function, I'm not sure if this will fix it (I do repeat this is an example, you need to adjust the functions so you get the right data)